# cannot connect to the backend server running port 8000 using nginx, django and docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I've spent two days trying to figure this out. I'm running docker containers that host a django+react website from a docker compose file.

I can access the website on port 80 (IP: http://52.90.163.11:80), but I can't seem to access the django admin panel on port 8000 (IP should be http://52.90.163.11:8000 but it doesn't work). I'm using AWS to host my website.

I simply want the backend container accessible via port 8000.

I have two docker compose files. One I build on my local machine. After building on local machine, I push the images to dockerhub. The second dockerfile resides on the AWS server, and uses images from the first build.

Here is my docker-compose file on my local machine to create the images.

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend/src
    command: gunicorn djreact.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
  pgdb:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend/gui 
    volumes:
      - react_build:/frontend/build
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx_setup.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - react_build:/var/www/react
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend

volumes:
  react_build:
  pgdata:
```

Here is my dockerfile on my AWS server. It uses the images created on my local machine.

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    image: ansariuminhaj/mynacode:mynacode-backend
    command: gunicorn djreact.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
  pgdb:
    image: ansariuminhaj/mynacode:postgres 
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  frontend:
    image: ansariuminhaj/mynacode:mynacode-frontend 
    volumes:
      - react_build:/frontend/build
  nginx:
    image: ansariuminhaj/mynacode:nginx
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx_setup.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - react_build:/var/www/react
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend

volumes:
  react_build:
  pgdata:
```

Here is my nginx conf file:

```
upstream api {
      server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    server_name 52.90.163.11;

    location / {
            proxy_read_timeout 300s;
            proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        root /var/www/react;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
            proxy_read_timeout 300s;
            proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

}
```

docker ps shows this on my AWS server.

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                           NAMES

9852c9738331   ansariuminhaj/mynacode:nginx              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp, :::80->8080/tcp   mynacode_nginx_1

b9709cbe37a1   ansariuminhaj/mynacode:mynacode-backend   "gunicorn djreact.ws…"   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp       mynacode_backend_1

5eebbbcae314   ansariuminhaj/mynacode:postgres           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   5432/tcp                                        mynacode_pgdb_1

I've tried creating a new AWS instance, docker system prune and recreate images/volume, but the problem still persists.

Comment: if you run the `docker-compose` locally can you access the backend over port 8000? what do you mean by it doesn't work? what happens?

Comment: Please improve the error details: is the port answering but it shows some error? can not connect to the port at all?

Comment: @bb4L Yes, if i run docker compose on my local machine, I can access port 8000 using localhost

Comment: @JuanmiTaboada There are no errors that I can see. I run docker compose build on my local machine, then I push them on docker hub. Then the second docker compose file is run on the aws server. It runs fine. I can access port 80 using the IP (you can click on it above). However, I cannot seem to access port 8000 :\

Comment: @MinhajUddinAnsari can you see anything in the logs when trying to access the backend?  are you sure the backend is running properly?

Comment: I think there's a problem. I thought localhost:8000 worked on my local machine with docker build and up on local machine but it doesn't. let me see what's going on

Comment: so I found the solution! The docker files are correct. I had to log onto the Amazon Instance and enable port 8000 so that it accepts requests on that port!

Comment: it was working on my local machine too in the end btw

Answer (score 2):

so I found the solution! The docker files are correct. I had to log onto the Amazon Instance and enable port 8000 so that it accepts requests on that port!